# getting same average values when execute my stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I am Getting same average values when i execute my stored procedure.

i am passing different TeamID's but Getting same Average values

**Stored procedure :**

```
GO
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspGetVote] Script Date: 9/3/2015 12:40:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetVote](@TeamID INT)

AS

BEGIN


select avg(VoteValue) as [AverageVoteValue] from Vote where datediff(day,getdate(),LastModifiedDateTime) <= 7 Group By TeamID order by AverageVoteValue

END
```

Please give me a correct query for that.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is:

```
GO
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspGetVote] Script Date: 9/3/2015 12:40:42 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetVote](@TeamID INT)

AS

BEGIN


SELECT AVG(VoteValue) AS [AverageVoteValue] FROM Vote 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),LastModifiedDateTime) <= 7 
AND TeamId = @TeamID
GROUP BY TeamId
ORDER BY AverageVoteValue

END
```